# Excel data validation - regular expressions?

Tags: excel, validation

I have a column in an Excel 2007 spreadsheet where I want the data to be restricted to values "COM[1-4] or 1-65535".  How can I get Excel to enforce this set of values?

TY,
Fred

Comment: Do you mean, how do you get another column to only show those values which meet your criteria?  Are you looking for range matching or exact matching?  Can you give some examples of values you want to match, and some values that are close but shouldn't match?

Comment: Would like the value to be one of COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4 or an int 1-65535

Answer (score 9):

You will need to create a custom VBA function (or Macro) that supports Regular Expressions. I've personally done this, so I know it's possible :-)

If this is a one-time issue, it can be solved by using a complex `FIND()`/`MID()`/`SUBSTITUTE()`, etc. (this is my day job, actually), but I wouldn't recommend this unless you want to stare at a possible 5 line cell full of Excel functions.

**Edit:** I will update this if you have or need further info to offer.

**Edit:** Here's how you can use regular expressions as a function in Excel:

```vb
Function REFIND(strValue As String, strPattern As String, Optional blnCase As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Dim blnValue As Boolean

    ' Create regular expression.
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.Pattern = strPattern
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = blnCase

    ' Do the search test.
    blnValue = objRegEx.Test(strValue)

    REFIND = blnValue End Function
End Function
```

Comment: If you could show how to do it in a macro that would be great.

Comment: I should be more specific. I've created functions. I don't care much for Macros (they have their place), but you'll still need to use a lot of the same custom VBA code. I'll attach the code above.

Comment: Perfect! Not sure why everyone else suggests regular excel functions whenever regex is suggested

Comment: @Foo_Chow if you can easily avoid using RegEx in Excel, do so; it will run faster without it. However, when something is dynamic enough that it requires regular expressions, it is a lot better than a list of raw text.

Answer (score 9):

Not very flexible, but you could use a Custom `Data Validation`, with this formula:

```
=OR(AND(LEN(A2)=4,LEFT(A2,3)="COM",MID(A2,4,1)>="1",MID(A2,4,1)<="4"),OR(AND(A2>=1,A2<=65535)))
```

I think this narrows it down to what you've specified in your comment.

Comment: +1 RegExp is overkill for what can be accomplished without VBA

Answer (score 4):

Use the below in Ribbon >> Data >> Data Validation. Then Allow = Custom and add the below in the Formula:

```
=OR(AND(E5 >= 1, E5 <= 65535), E5 = "COM1", E5 = "COM2", E5 = "COM3", E5 = "COM4")
```

Answer (score 0):

For this specific question, using standard Data Validation would have worked with no VBA, Regex or formulas needed:

Allow: List
Source: "COM1,COM2,COM3,COM4,1-65535"

This also provides a dropdown list in the cell to help user.

Comment: The list would need to contain the numbers 1 through 65535...